# Is it possible to navigate to a different widget view on click of a button using iOS 17 interactive widgets?

Tags: ios, swiftui, ipad, widgetkit, ios17

I am new to developing widgets for iPads, and I understand that iOS 17 lets developers create interactive widgets for iPads that support buttons and toggles.

I have a requirement where, with the click of a button, I want to navigate to the next view inside the widget. Does navigation work inside a widget?

I couldn't find much information anywhere regarding this.

Comment: There is no mention of navigation anywhere in the documentation. If navigation is not supported, then is it possible to add a next button to reload the current view and a back button to load the previous view again?